# Data value is appearing instead of data label in grid export

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, export

I have an options array in below format.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'value' => string 'one' (length=3)
      'label' => string 'Number One' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'value' => string 'two' (length=3)
      'label' => string 'Number Two' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'value' => string 'three' (length=5)
      'label' => string 'Number Three' (length=12)
```

In admin grid column data label is appearing, which is correct. 
But when I am exporting the same grid the instead of data label, the data value is appearing the exported CSV and XML.
The Attribute is of type `select`.
Code is ui_component xml is as follows

```
<column name="mycol" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Anshu\Mygrid\Model\Mygrid\Source\Myvalue"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">My Value</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @PankajPareek No, I didn't found any solution for this. Kindly post it here if you get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I have used in my custom module.

In this file add below line on code:

> app/code/Custom/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" type="Custom\Module\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" />
```

Now create a new file and read the comment which I have mentioned in my code which you have replace as per your requirement.

> app/code/Custom/Module/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Export;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

/**
 * Class ConvertToCsv
 */
class ConvertToCsv extends \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv
{
    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directory;

    /**
     * @var MetadataProvider
     */
    protected $metadataProvider;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $pageSize = null;

    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param MetadataProvider $metadataProvider
     * @param int $pageSize
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Filter $filter,
        \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
        $pageSize = 200
    ) {
        $this->filter           = $filter;
        $this->directory        = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
        $this->pageSize         = $pageSize;

        parent::__construct($filesystem, $filter, $metadataProvider, $pageSize);
    }

    /**
     * Returns CSV file
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getCsvFile()
    {
        $component = $this->filter->getComponent();

        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';

        $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
        $this->filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider();
        $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
        $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
        $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();

        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
        $i = 1;
        $searchCriteria = $dataProvider->getSearchCriteria()
            ->setCurrentPage($i)
            ->setPageSize($this->pageSize);
        $totalCount = (int) $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getTotalCount();

        while ($totalCount > 0) {
            $items = $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getItems();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if($component->getName() == 'custom_item_listing') { // replace this listing by your listing.xml file name
                    $item->setCustomValue('test'); // this will be your custom attribute/column which needs to be exported as per your requirement.
                }
                $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
                $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
            }
            $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage(++$i);
            $totalCount = $totalCount - $this->pageSize;
        }
        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();

        return [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $file,
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ];
    }
}
```

This solution is working fine for me. Hope this will work for you as well.

Thank you.